# How to upgrade the boost to specified version?

Tags: centos, boost

I want to upgrade the boost to 1.59 in CentOS7.2(1511):

Because I cmake my mysql source code, there comes the error:

```
CMake Warning at cmake/boost.cmake:266 (MESSAGE):
  Boost minor version found is 53 we need 59
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:491 (INCLUDE)
```

I tried use :

```
yum install boost-1.59.0
```

but failed:

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum install boost-1.59.0
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.cn99.com
 * extras: mirrors.cn99.com
 * updates: mirrors.shuosc.org
No package boost-1.59.0 available.
```

---

**EDIT**

My OS version is `CentOS7.2(1511)`.

Comment: Don't build MySQL from source when your distribution has a perfectly good package manager available. Use `yum install mysql` instead. Better yet, go with MariaDB.

Comment: I want to know this issue solution. please help me about that. thank you very much.

Comment: *why* do you want to build MySQL from source? It's clear from your question that you haven't got a clue where to begin -- from the looks of it, your version of CentOS doesn't have the needed version of libboost yet either so you'd have to compile that from source as well, and likewise any dependencies for libboost that you can't yet meet and so on and so on.

Comment: I'm not trying to be a jerk here, but I am getting the sense that you're running into an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. What problem are you hoping to solve by installing MySQL from source?

Comment: Why are you guys asking about installing MySQL?   The OP is clearly saying they want to upgrade Boost.  Even if the error being generated is from a MySQL compile - Boost is clearly the problem.  If you run Centos 7, you know that the Boost libs are woefully out of date.  Try answering the guys question (about upgrading Boost) ....